# ARC and local variables

Tags: iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm currently busy converting my code to ARC and ran into a little bit of trouble using local variables. As they are only kept in memory as long as the compiler thinks I need them, they usually get released after the last method call to them.

Unfortunately, my application contains a HUD with custom stuff in it, like UIButtons. The selectors of those are pointing to the HUD itself and so I always get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS because the controller was released after it was instantiated.

Is there any solution to this besides creating an instance variable in my class header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's really the same thing as putting an iVar in the header, you can at least keep things cleaner by creating a private category at the top of the .m file that defines properties you can hold the UIButtons in.

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *myButton;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize myButton;

....

self.myButton = thingThatisHoldingYourButton;

// Now for the block
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the exact situation you are in, but something has to keep a reference to the controller... if you really felt the need you could also use the compiler directives saying you were maintaining the memory yourself and just retain it.  But then who would release it?

Comment: but isn't keeping my method call to `addSubview` the controller around? I mean when we had to manually do memory management it did, so why did it stop working?

Comment: It keeps the views around, but not the controller.  The controller has to be maintained separately.. also the view controller that has the main controller would really like to know there is a sub-controller.  I think it worked before because you had a bug that kept in in memory, ARC has now cleaned up that error.

Comment: SO there is no other chance than declaring an outlet, isn't it? what about things like `__block`?

Comment: Like I said, I am confused about your situation.  Just using the controller in the block should retain it, but it sounds like you need to have the controller live after the block has finished executing (since there is a callback to your controller).  If that is the case you need to keep a reference somewhere, not in the block.

Comment: Okay, that was definetly what I was looking for. Thanks!